# Using the verb "let" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: verbs

According to the Oxford dictionary the word **let** is a verb.

I would like to know if it acts as verb in the following sentence:

> Let's go to see him on Tuesday.

It seems to me that the main verb here is *go*.  Does *let* also act as a verb?  If so, how?

Comment: It is the imperative "let us". The speaker is suggesting  that something should be done.  *Let's cross the street*.  It is complemented with a clause headed by the (bare, unmarked) infinitive form of the verb (e.g. go, cross).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am volunteering with a student who has to break up sentences in to its constituents (subjects, verbs, objects etc.) I understand why we use let in everyday speech, but what I cant understand is whether it is working as a verb in the sentence I gave.  Any further suggestions are appreciated,

Comment: What do you think it is working as?

Comment: See [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/let-let-s). One thing it does not state is that we can use the verb  *let* of *let's*  as the only verb in a sentence. This is because it is a conjugated verb, 
 whereas the infinitive that usually follows it is not–thus grammatically *let* is the "main verb."  Example... Person 1: *Let's kiss*. Person 2 *Yes, let's*. The infinitive *kiss*   from Person 1's sentence is understood.

Comment: @Clare Completely wrong analysis, See my answer for the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Let's go to see him on Tuesday.*

This is called a *LET*-imperative.

Yes, "let" is a verb, but it has been bleached of its normal meaning of "allow" and serves solely as a marker of this special type of imperative construction.  It's a plain form (infinitive) verb, so it is not conjugated, of course. It's the verb following "let" that is understood with a 1st person plural subject.

You are right that the 'main' verb is "go". It's a catenative verb that has "us" as direct object followed by the infinitival clause "go to see him" as second complement